# Running GloVe on Windows

Tags: windows, nlp, stanford-nlp

Is it possible to install GloVe on Windows 10?

From https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/ :

> Compile the source:  `cd GloVe-1.2 && make`

But how can I run "make" in Windows?

Comment: Probably best to visit their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe) and open an issue, to either have the documentation improve, or a Windows-compatible build system integrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, there are two possible workarounds for you. You could install something like [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) and build official implementation of Glove on your Windows system. Or you could try installing Glove as a Python package (like [this one](https://github.com/maciejkula/glove-python) or like [this one](https://pypi.org/project/glove/)) through `pip` or `conda` or something, and work with Glove through Python. But, as the authors of these packages say, they could *contain a tremendous amount of bugs*. So trying to build the official Glove should be the best solution.

But, actually, if you do not need to train the model, installing Glove is not necessary, and you can just download pre-trained models from [here](http://vectors.nlpl.eu/repository/#), for example.