# install glove_python library on windows 10

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrJRJ.png)I want to install glove_python library on windows 10 so There was an error , I tried to download ( visual build tools and mingw ) but I got the same error What should I do ?

```
Failed to build glove-python
Installing collected packages: glove-python
    Running setup.py install for glove-python ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Green\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Green\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w9uo706s\\glove-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Green\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w9uo706s\\glove-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-i5e8cm27\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Green\anaconda3\Include\glove-python'
         cwd: C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-w9uo706s\glove-python\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    building 'glove.glove_cython' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio"
```

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the error so it would be more clear and we can help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [running glove on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463453/running-glove-on-windows)